# Why Android Lint strictly discourages the use of Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.RIGHT?

Tags: android, lint, gravity, android-lint, android-gravity

I understand that texts may be `LEFT` or `RIGHT` on different languages, so that `END` or `START` may be useful for international apps.

However, LEFT or RIGHT as Gravity are also simple placement of things. If I want my button or icon to be aligned to the RIGHT, why on earth does lint complain on using END instead?  Probably, if use END, the layout will become broken on a foreign device.

Comment: For the same reason as far as i know. Button placement are also right-left oriented on those devices

Comment: Because in right-to-left languages all the UI goes right-to-left, not only the letters. [Here](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9) an example.